# What does happen to code flow when a AS3 listener is called?

Tags: flash, event-handling, actionscript-3

To be more specific, I want to know what does happen to the following code when listener is called to handle this event in AS3.
In fact, whether the flow is interrupted while the function `handleAnyEvent()` is running or if the flow goes on, calling the others functions while `handleAnyEvent()` is running in another thread.
Can anyone explain the exatcly flow of this code?

```
anything.addEventListener(Event.ANY_EVENT, handleAnyEvent);
function handleAnyEvent(e:Event):void{
//Do something here
}

anything.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.ANY_EVENT));
somefunction();
otherfunction();
examplefunction();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `dispatchEvent` blocks. However, it is assumed that the event handlers will take a trivial amount of time since ActionScript has few ways of performing non-trivial blocking operations like I/O.

Comment: Dou you meaning that "somefunction(), otherfunction(), examplefunction() only is called when handleAnyEvent is finished?

Comment: Yes. I just spent 4 hours learning this the hard way and thought it might help others save time.

Answer (score 1):

Flash runs in a single thread. (yes, there are Workers, but that's not what the event system uses by default)